# Laravel: .env file showing for some domain

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I made some projects on laravel with a different version like 5.0, 5.6
My .env file is placed in the root folder and .env code is visible publicly.

I use the below code for hiding the .env file in htaccess

```
# Hide a specific file
    <Files .env>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Files>
```

above code is working in some domain like myproject.io but not working in project.ai

Please help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you got multiple apps on the same domain or is it just the one? Also, where have you put the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @RossWilson hi, All application on a different domain and my htaccess is in the root folder

Comment: What's the difference between the two domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with protecting all the dot(.) files?

In nginx

```
# Block dot files
location ~ /. {
    deny  all;
}
```

Apache

```
<FilesMatch "^\.">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternate is update your root .htaccess with the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php

</IfModule>
```